# Vue and .NET Core integration (+authentication) choice

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vue.js, integration

As far as I understand that, there are two major options for Vue and .NET Core integration within single MVC/Razor project.

**Option 1.**

MVC/Razor-rendered non-reactive page is used for authentication with built-in ASP.NET Identity. Vue is not involved for authentication/authorization at all. As soon as users are authenticated, they are redirected to another MVC/Razor page that is used as a HTML template for Vue. It’s possible to combine MVC/Razor rendering and Vue. For example, user name on the top of the page can be rendered by MVC but button actions and data tables will be further processed by Vue. It’s possible to use many pages (so it will be MPA, not SPA), it comes naturally. Using *.vue files is not possible. MVC routing seems to be primary routing option (not sure, would be possible to combine with Vue routing and whether any needs for that). Vue JS files can reside anywhere in the project, for example, can be bound to the HTML pages similarly as CS files in Razor pages do (and it’s nice). Then, all these JS files along with Vue itself can be bundled to the wwwroot by Webpack. Vue CLI is not available but seems there is no need for that.

**Option 2.**

MVC/Razor is not used for rendering user pages at all. Authentication occurs by third-party solutions like IdentityServer and with Vue-managed pages. .NET Core is used exclusively as a WebAPI for Vue and to hold a project. Vue part is totally independent from the MVC/Razor part, they even render pages to the different HTTP ports so proxy is needed to convert Vue HTTP port to the MVC/Razor HTTP port to make Vue works in the single project. We can use either Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions or NuGet third-party VueCliMiddleware for that. All Vue files typically reside within a ClientApp folder and then are building to the wwwroot folder. Using *.vue files is possible. Vue CLI is available and recommended to scaffold new application to the ClientApp folder (but further CLI seems is not needed). Vue router seems to be the only option for routing. SPA seems to be the primary choice as a structure (not sure, whether MPA is readily available option). Webpack is still used for building Vue app from the ClientApp to the wwwroot.

I started mu Vue journey with Option 1 even without webpack and npm, just with CDN tag on the one of the Razor pages and it works very well. For me Option 1 seems less complex while more flexible. My primary concern is that Microsoft uses Option 2 as a built-in templates for Angular and React in Visual Studio, so I probably is missing something and soon I will be pushed to rewrite my app to the Option 2.

What you guys think which option is better and whether my understanding explained above, is correct?

Comment: I started out with option 1 but as the project started to get bit involved, I switched to option 2. What did you end up doing?  I'm now working on vue SPA use .net core's already existing OAuth/OIDC authentication/authorization.  Have you done anything with identity for your vue/.net app?

Comment: I ended up with Option 1 (Vue pages for MVC project) and got the project running. However, it seems that Option 2 (Vue as a frontend and Asp.Net as a backend separated) is the only option to evolve. The primary reason is the common practice. I mean, even though MVC/Vue mix looks good, it's uncommon so it's hard to move forward because most technlogies are focused on Option 2 type projects. So I slowly move my project to a new Identity Server/Vue FrontEnd/ASP BackEnd platform.

Comment: @Niksr Maybe the trend is true, but real life business apps (either new or old) are using this vue / mvc mix. So keeping both worlds together can be a necessity in some cases. Have you found any resources for the option#1 way?

Comment: No. I focused entirely on Option 2. Even though Option 1 is workable and looks simpler, at least for small projects, it seems it's not broadly supported.