How to integrate ASP.NET Core Identity with Vue.js Frontend for Authentication Using Razor Pages?
I set up my project by following the ASP.NET Core app with Vue.js in Visual Studio guide and configured my frontend and backend as separate applications, with the frontend using a proxy setup in vite.config.ts to communicate with the backend.
Current authentication Implementation
I have implemented authentication by following the guide on using Identity to secure a Web API backend for SPAs, which led me to create custom UI for login.
In my current setup frontend has separate login pages that interact with the new identity API endpoint.
I have been checking whether user is logged and checking the protect routes in the frontend on every route by trying to fetch the user info.
router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {
  const authStore = useAuthStore();

  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    const isSignedIn = await authStore.isSignedIn();

    if (!isSignedIn) {
      // Redirect to sign-in page if not authenticated
      next({ path: '/signin' });
    } else {
      // Proceed if authenticated
      next();
    }
  } else {
    // Route does not require authentication
    next();
  }
});

To check whether user is already signed in:
async isSignedIn() {
      const userInfo = await fetchUserInfo();

      const isValid = !!(userInfo && userInfo.email && userInfo.email.length > 0);

      this.$patch({
        name: userInfo?.email,
        isAuthenticated: isValid
      })

      return isValid;
    },

async function fetchUserInfo() {
  try {
    const response = await fetch('manage/info', {
      method: 'GET'
    });

    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error('Not authenticated');
    }

    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Fetch user info error:', error);
    return null; // Return null if an error occurs
  }
}

What I want to achieve
Instead of using the identity API endpoints, I wanted to use the scaffolded default Identity UI for login, which would separate out the logic of authentication from the frontend, and I am little bit doubting on myself that i may not do the authentication flow correct on the frontend.
Also, the new identity endpoints are not easily extended, which doesn't allow the most of the desired field to be added on the different identity endpoints.
I want to use the cookies instead of the JWT token.
I do not wanted to use external authentication providers (e.g., OAuth 2 or IdentityServer).
I want to use only ASP.NET Core Identity for user management and authentication.
Questions

Is it possible to integrate the Razor-based authentication flow while keeping the Vue.js with the vite setup?


Want to use razor pages for user registration and login instead of using identity API endpoints. You can try to create an ASP.NET Core MVC project first, add and configure ASP.NET Identity, redirect users to Vue pages after authentication, and then check the cookie to determine the user's login status, thereby protecting restricted routes.
But if you want to separate the front and back ends, you need to use API endpoints. You can refer to this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62080433/vue-and-net-core-integration-authentication-choice

I want to set up separate front-end and back-end applications, but for authentication (login, registration, etc.), I want to use the Identity UI. I've already scaffolded the Identity UI and it is in my project. My question is how to use it with a Vue.js front-end setup. Since Razor Pages and the front-end can't be served from the same domain, if I redirect from Vue.js, I will need to redirect to a different domain. Essentially, I want to keep the front-end on its own domain but serve the Identity UI, and I would like to use cookie-based authentication instead of access tokens. @YuningDuan

Razor and Vue page can be served from the same domain.  Ex: mydomain . com / razorlogin/login
